# The number of points doesn't work for more than 166..

Tags: vb.net, graph, charts

I am trying to programatically get my Chart object to appear. I have been able to get the Chart to appear using the Design file, but for what I am doing, I need to understand how the Chart Control works programatically.  This is my code:

```
Dim wavesGraph As New Chart()
Dim chartarea  As New ChartArea
Dim vn1Series  As New Series("VN1", SeriesChartType.Line)

wavesGraph.ChartAreas.Add(chartarea)
wavesGraph.Series.Add(vn1Series)

Console.WriteLine("Here1")
wavesGraph.ChartAreas(0).Visible        = True
wavesGraph.ChartAreas(0).AxisY2.Enabled = AxisEnabled.True
wavesGraph.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.Title    = "Network Voltage"

If (WavesIsI) Then
    wavesGraph.ChartAreas(0).AxisY2.Title = "Network Current"
Else
    wavesGraph.ChartAreas(0).AxisY2.Title = "Differential Volts"
End If

Dim rand As New Random
Console.WriteLine("Here2")

For i As Integer = 0 To 500
    wavesGraph.Series(0).Points.AddXY(i, rand.Next(-255, 255))
Next

wavesGraph.Enabled = True
wavesGraph.Visible = True
Console.WriteLine("Here3")
Me.Controls.Add(wavesGraph)
```

The above program doesn't work. If I change the range to be from 0 to 166, then it works fine.

Please anyone help me solve this issue

Comment: are you talking about the range 'For i As Integer = 0 To 500'? Only works up to 166? Can you also define what you mean by 'works'

Comment: Yes I was talking about the value of i. If the value of i is more than 166, then it gives an exception and does not plot the graph. If the number of elements to plot is less than 166, then the graph is plotted.

Comment: what's the exception?

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.